# When I checking the hot terminal in the socket, multimeter shows the current through me?

Tags: current-measurement, socket, terminal

I set my multimeter in AC voltage measurement, connected + wire of multimeter to the hot terminal of the electrical socket, and take - wire in my hand. Now it measures the voltage. This procedure checks is the terminal "hot". Multimeter shows 0,1 V.

I am wondering, what if it shows the current trough me(socket's AC 220 V divided by my ~2200 Omhs) if touch the terminal of the electrical socket, i.e., in this case 0,1 A(which is a killing value)?

---

It seems people didn't understand what did I mean. It's my fault. Clearly:

I use [Multimeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multimeter), that switched to voltmeter mode. Below you can see the "circuit". I know what voltmeter measures, **but** I noticed, that the value it shows is pretty similar to current value through me, in case of no voltmeter, i.e. no additional huge resistance, i.e. only resistance of my body.

[image]

Comment: It may mean a shocking or masochistic experience if measuring current between you and hot and you might not be able to let go. Then what?

Comment: It does not show CURRENT through you, when you meter the VOLTAGE. It is nonsense.

Answer (score 5):

This is a really stupid thing to do.

You are measuring the difference in voltage between the mains and the ground through your body's capacitance.

---

You have not given a make and model of the multimeter or a link to its datasheet so it is not possible to construct an equivalent circuit. The problems are that you are using a meter for purposes other than which it was intended and you have no guarantee of safety. You are relying on current limiting due to the input input impedance of the meter and the very short clearances between the very many switch contacts - including those which select the mA ranges and these are typically fused (if at all) at 200 mA and this is more than enough to kill.

---

This is a really stupid thing to do.

Comment: You wrong. There is a huge measurement device resistance also in the "loop'

Comment: You hope. The meter is not rated for medical safety. There are small distances between the switch contacts and you have to expect that it can fail in an unsafe manner. The meter can fail and you can be killed.

Comment: @Transistor could you edit that into your answer? I think that the meter potentially shorting, connecting you directly to mains is important to explain, so people feel less tempted to do this!

Comment: @marcelm: Done, thanks.

Comment: Please, check updated question

Comment: Your diagram confirms how I interpreted your question. You are running mains current through your body and the current is limited only by the resistance of the multimeter.